# Creating an if statement that checks the value of an obect and subsequently assigns a value to another object

Tags: if-statement, django-models, conditional-statements

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_US>
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  text = models.TextField(blank=True)
  created_date = models.DateTimeField(default>
  published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank>
  ARCHEOLOGY='Archeology'
  CRIME='Crime'
  EDUCATION='Education'
  IMMIGRATION='Immigration'
  CONFLICTS='Conflicts'
  DISASTER='Disaster'
  ENVIRONMENT='Environment'
  RELIGION='Religion'
  SCANDALS='Scandals'
  MUSICNEWS='Music News'
  CELEBRITYNEWS='Celebrity News'
  WILDNATURE='Wild Nature'
  NATURALSCIENCE='Natural Science'
  US ='U.S.'
  OPINION='Opinion'
  ENTERTAINMENT='Entertainment'
  SCIENCE='Science'
  WORLD='World'
news_categories = [
 (ARCHEOLOGY, 'Archeology'),
 (CELEBRITYNEWS,'Celebrity News'),
 (CONFLICTS,'Conflicts'),
 (CRIME,'Crime'),
 (DISASTER,'Disaster'),
 (EDUCATION,'Education'),
 (ENVIRONMENT,'Environment'),
 (IMMIGRATION,'Immigration'),
 (MUSICNEWS,'Music News'),
 (NATURALSCIENCE,'Natural Science'),
 (RELIGION,'Religion'),
 (SCANDALS,'Scandals'),
 (WILDNATURE,'Wild Nature'),]
category = models.CharField(
 max_length=15,
 choices=news_categories,
 default=ARCHEOLOGY,
)


ssubcategory=[
 (WORLD,'World'),
 (US,'U.S.'),
]
subcategory= models.CharField(
 max_length=15,
 choices=ssubcategory,
 default=US,
)
def whoops(self,):
 if self.category==RELIGION:
  self.subcategory=WORLD
  return self.subcategory

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

I have this code which makes a dropdown of the list and assigns the value as a category when you make the post.

How do I make a variable to hold multiple choices from this list as another value?

Essentially each item on the list link to a page filled with posts containing that category (crime, religion etc..).

But how would I make an object called outer-category that's chosen when the category is chosen (i.e. when I choose religion as a category for a post, I want it to automatically add itself to an oitercategory called the world

I would guess it involves and if statement?

```
(If 'catergory'=='religion: 'outercategory'='world'
```

But that doesnt seem to be working for me.

Comment: What are your models?

Comment: I updated to add the entire models page